# Is it correct to say "None can stop me" without mentioning a specific group of people?

Tags: pronouns

Is it correct to say "None can stop me?" I feel like "No one can stop me" is the one I've seen used most often, but I'm not sure if "none" works too? Does there have to be a specific context where there are several people: e.g. "There are many who will try, but none can stop me." And in other contexts (without specifically mentioning other people) "none" doesn't work?

Comment: Unless you can identify a specific issue here that would be of interest to folks on ELU (and I can't think of any), I think that this would be more suited to [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"None" is rare as compared to "no one" or "nobody", but it is correct.

[image]

This is possibly so because "none" means also "not one of them", and so it is not as unequivocal as "no one" or "nobody".

> (SOED) **1** No one, not any one *of* a number of persons or things;

Comment: I immediately thought of _None shall sleep_, one common English translation for the famous operatic aria _Nessun dorma_ - OK in poetic language, but not usual in everyday speech.

Comment: @KateBunting It's true that in this [page of examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22none%20can%20stop%20me%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en), "none" is found in many books from writers from the Indian subcontinent, however, there is a non negligible number of cases due to Anglo-Saxon writers (in great part books of recent origin).

Comment: But most of those are poetic, religious or 'mythical' language.